# Mockito doThrow for JMS Client not throwing Exception

Tags: jms, mockito, testcase

I am writing unit test case for my JMS client. But `doThrow` is not throwing any  error. Looks like it is because my `sendMessage` method has return type as void and I have finally block to close the connection.

Is anyone facing the same issue?

```
doThrow(new JMSException("Expected")).when(messageSubmitter).sendMessage(message);
```

Here's the `sendMessage` method:

```
public void sendMessage(String message) throws JMSException,Exception {

    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    try {
         connection.start();
         try {
             Session session =  connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
             try {
                 MessageProducer messageProducer =session.createProducer(messageQueue);
                 try {
                         TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                         message.setText(messageQueue);
                         messageProducer.send(message);
                     }
                 } finally {
                     JmsUtils.closeProducer(messageProducer);
                 }
             } finally {
                 JmsUtils.closeSession(session);
             }
         } finally {
             JmsUtils.closeConnection(connection);
         }
     } catch (JMSException ex) {
                  throw ex;
     } catch(Exception ex) {

          throw ex;
      }

}
```

This is my test method and above is my jms client method.

```
@Test 
public void myAction_should_return_failure_result_in_case_of_JMS_excepti‌​on() throws Exception { 
     // given 
     String message ="Test";     
     doThrow(exception).when(MessageSubmitter.sendMessage(message‌​);
     //when 
     ActionResult processingResult = Submitter.myActionOn("123"); 
     //then 
     assertFalse(processingResult.isProcessedSuccessfully()); 
     assertEquals(exception, processingResult.getException()); 
}
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of the test?

Comment: This is my test method and above is my jms client method. Will this do?
@Test
    public void myAction_should_return_failure_result_in_case_of_JMS_exception() throws Exception {
        // given
  String message ="Test";
        doThrow(exception).when(MessageSubmitter.sendMessage(message);
       
        //when
        ActionResult processingResult = Submitter.myActionOn("123");

        //then
        assertFalse(processingResult.isProcessedSuccessfully());
        assertEquals(exception, processingResult.getException());
    }

Comment: It's really hard to read any code like that in the comments. Please [edit] your question and add the code there.

Comment: The whole thing doesn't make much sense. You are giving us the code from the `sendMessage` method, but then it looks like you mock that method (`doThrow...`), so that the actual code becomes meaningless. And the code that would actually be interesting (`Submitter.myAction`) is nowhere to be seen. Sorry, that's a mess and it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you with it this way.